# "active" tab in answer section is not showing the recent answer in top

Tags: bug, activity-tab, last-activity

Today I see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21882897/laravel-artisan-not-working?answertab=active#tab-top) from "active" tab in the home page.

After navigating to the answer section with **active** tab, the recent answer is not in the top.

The accepted answer is in top, it was answered on Fen 19, 2014. Why the recent answer is not in the top ?

> [image: active tab]

Comment: This is by design. Accepted answer is displayed before all the other answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign); the accepted answer is **always stuck to the top**, regardless of votes or other activity.

[Mike M.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2850651/mike-m) also mentioned that:

> Self accepts do not stick the answer to the top.

This is to highlight the answer that the OP found helpful (and therefore accepted), but may not be the best or most cohesive answer.

Comment: It is mentioned in any where? like help-center or any FAQ post?

Comment: @Arulkumar I don't think there is, but there is [a post on the main Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/268666/keeping-special-status-for-accepted-answers-without-sticking-them-to-top-forever) referencing it.

Comment: Yes, as Mike said, self-accepts don't stick the answer to the top.

Comment: Oh, cool. I needed to rephrase that, but then I thought I'd better double-check first.